# After login, unable to use mouse or keyboard

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, mouse

Let me start off by saying I have tried several fresh installs of 13.04 and each time the mouse and keyboard can not function properly. I'm able to move the mouse but can not click anything; as for the keyboard I'm unable to launch anything either. I then decided to reinstall 12.10 and everything worked fine so I upgraded to 13.04 which then yields the same issue, unable to click and use keyboard. Not sure what to do here, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it with another keyboard and mouse? Or unplugging and plugging it back in?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Turns out it was a driver issue for graphics. Logged into safe boot, Installed nvidia drivers and everything works just fine.